# Recommend cache updating strategy

Tags: performance, caching, architecture, distributed-computing, distributed-caching

Our site is divided into several smaller sites recently, which are then distributed in different IDCs.

One of these sites serves user authentication and other user-related services, the other sites access it through web services.

On every site that fetches data remotely, we make a local cache so that we don't have to go remote every time user information is needed.

What cache updating strategy would you recommend to ensure data integrity?

Comment: Do you need real-time data integrity, or some delay in "publishing" actual data possible?

Comment: Thx for replying :) Yes, at least it should be close to real-time, because it is an SNS application, and if a user update her nick name in one site, the change should take place as soon as possible on the other sites.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the updated-policy close to realtime, you definitely need the cache-invalidation notification engine.

There are 2 possible implementation models for it:

1.Pull
Main server pulls child-servers with notification messages like `"resourceID=34392 not more valid in your cache"`. 
This message should be sent on each data update on main server.

1. Poll
   Each child-server ask main server about the cache item validity right before serving it to user.
   Ofcourse, in this case, main server should keep the list of objects updated during last cache-lifetime period, and respond to `"If-object-was-updated"` requests very quickly.

As you see in both cases, your main server should trigger an event on each data change.
In first case this event will be transferred via 'notification bus' to child server, and in second case this event will be stored in `recently-updated-objects` list. 
So both options need some code changes on main server.

As for me the second options is much more easy to implement in common, but it`s  very depends of the software stack you're using.

Comment: Our application is written in Python, I wonder if there is any third-party library we can use as a notification engine.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not familiar with Python-technologies, but the easiest implementation way i see is: store the objectID's to be re-cached in memcached; setup nginx as reverse proxy between child servers and main server; make nginx to maintain the object caching and work directly with the list, stored in memcached.  Anyway as i said, it's very task specific and need more investigations. You can contact me if you want to discuss this more detailed.